# Inhabilitar botones del slider

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Hola programadores, estoy haciendo la función de un slider la tengo casi por completo finalizada pero solo me falta un pequeño detalle que es el siguiente el slider tiene dos botones en cada extremo uno para ir hacia delante y otro para ir hacia atrás, este slider tiene 8 elementos lo que quiero lograr es que cuando llegue al último elemento se desactive uno de los dos botones ya sea  hacia delante o hacia atrás para evitar un siclo infinito de la función.

El código es un poco largo les compartiré el enlace para que puedan ver el código, agradecería su colaboración para ayudarme a resolver este problema muchas gracias.
**
[image: imagen del slider]

[enlace del slider](https://codepen.io/jesussanchez1701/pen/JjNLqJz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final de la función nextCarrusel pones

```
//maximo para el total de imágenes
var maximo = document.querySelectorAll("li.product-DE").length-1;  
if (datosLista >= maximo)   
    {
     event.currentTarget.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
     }
```

Al final de la función prevCarrusel pones

```
/*deshabilitar cuando llega al inicio de la lista*/    
if (datosLista <= 0)   
    {
     event.currentTarget.disabled = 'disabled');
     }
 else{     
    document.getElementById("Next").disabled = false;     
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes poner la lógica en tus funciones `prev` y `next` para ver en que elemento vas y desactivar/activar los botones.

En `prevCarousel()`, al final:

```
if (datosLista <= 0) {
      document.getElementById("Previus").disabled = true;
    } else {
       document.getElementById("Next").disabled = false;
    }
```

y en `nextCarousel()` al final:

```
    if (datosLista >= 7) { // Mejor usar una constante con el # de elementos
      document.getElementById("Next").disabled = true
    } else {
      document.getElementById("Next").disabled = false
    }
```